# Sources for detailed LIDAR-based ground cover classification data? (USA/New York State)

Tags: data-request, usa

Does anyone know of a source of processed LIDAR data that shows heights/elevations of the understory and of the tree-tops at around 1 meter horizontal resolution?  I'm also looking for density maps<sup>1</sup> for the understory (ideally 0 to 2 meters AGL).  So far I've only been able to find bare earth DEMs for the area I'm working in (New York State, USA).

Here's the data I've found so far:

- [New York State LIDAR point clouds](ftp://ftp.gis.ny.gov/elevation/LIDAR/)
- [New York State LIDAR-derived bare-earth 1m DEMs](ftp://ftp.gis.ny.gov/elevation/DEM/)
- [LIDAR point clouds (United States)](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov) (search for Elevation Source Data (3DEP) - Lidar, IfSAR)

<sup>1</sup> e.g. returns per square meter less than 2 meters above ground level

Something like this (B & C) is  what I'm looking for: [image: Understory - EROS LiDAR]
Credit: EROS Fire Science Team, Earth Resources Observation and Science Center. Public domain.
https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/understory-eros-lidar